# Windows cannot resolve a CNAME records in bind

Tags: windows, networking, dns, hostname, bind

In linux I use **bind** - version: 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.17.rc1.el6_4.5 -
configured in such a way that  2 host names share the same IP address.

The 2 host names are **server2** and **server3** and they must share the same IP **192.168.1.62** , for this purpose I used a CNAME record as shown below :

```
$TTL 86400
@       IN      SOA     server1.eda. admi.server1.eda. (                        
                    2 ; serial
                    28800 ; refresh
                    7200 ; retry
                    604800 ; expire 
                    86400 ; ttl
                    )


@                NS      server1.
                 NS      8.8.8.8.                 

server1                 A       192.168.1.60
server3                 A       192.168.1.62
server2                 CNAME   server3
```

The domain is **eda**

What happens is that on **Windows** the ping to server1 and server3 without the domain works, while the ping to server2 works only with the domain, that is with ping server2.eda as shown below :

[image]

The only way to make ping server2 works is to append **eda** suffix on on the DNS tab in ‘Advanced TCP/IP Settings‘ window.

[image]

Below I have reported the image of nslookup

[image]

[image]

How can i make Windows resolve hostname server2 without adding the .eda suffix? Which it already does with server1 and server3

Comment: What other suffixes are configured in this system? What does `nslookup server2` and `nslookup server2.` give you? Also, your NS records look very odd. Most likely unrelated to the problem, but the first one should be either `server1` or `server1.eda.`, and what is the 8.8.8.8 doing there? (NS records don't accept IP addresses, and even then, 8.8.8.8 *isn't* authoritative for your domain.)

Comment: the only suffixes is eda

Comment: I don't believe you HAVE to use a CNAME. most DNS Server implementations let you create multiple A records for a single IP. the reason CNAMEs are recommended is that you only need to change one A rec to change the IP for it and all its aliases, but your domain doesn't appear to be so complicated that you can't easily update both A recs if the IP changes.

Comment: @FrankThomas I've tried to create multiple A with same ip address, but the behaviour is the same, without suffix server2 is not translated to ip address

Comment: whats weird about this, isn't that server2 isnt working, but that server1 and server3 are. the config on the DNS tab of your IP configuration dialog, is responsible for what they call "Search Domains". without a search domain set, short name references to servers should not work at all. I would make sure your primary DNS suffix is set in the system control panel, and that you select "Append primary and connection specific DNS suffixes". All this leads me to wonder if the hostnames that do work are actually being resolved by DNS or by SMB/NBT or mDNS. that would explain everything if they were.